# Arduino Uno to RS232 Numeric Display

Tags: serial-port, arduino-uno

Please help...  I have an RS232 numeric display that I am trying to control using Arduino Uno.  The display uses 9600 baud, 8 data bits, 2 stop bits, and no parity.  I uploaded the code from Arduino 1.0.6, then crosswired pins 0 and 1 to an RS232-TTL MAX3232 connected to the display with a null modem cable (DCE to DCE)

When I press reset on the Uno, the TX led flashes and the bytearray being sent should cause the display to show '37', but the display doesn't change. Also, a straight cable from the RS232-TTL to a PC running hyperterminal doesn't show output.

```html
byte bytearray[]={0x1F, 0x57, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,  0x33, 0x37, 0x4, 0xD};

void setup()
{
    // set the speed & config = data bits 8, parity none, stop bits 2
    Serial.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N2);
    Serial.write(bytearray, sizeof(bytearray));
}  

void loop()
{
}
```

On the other hand with a direct connection from my PC RS232 to the display, this VB code works perfectly.

```html
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Form1

    Dim SerialPort1 As New SerialPort

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        SerialPort1.PortName = "COM5"
        SerialPort1.RtsEnable = True
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8             'this is required for binary data
        SerialPort1.StopBits = 2
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600      'use whatever speed is required
        SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None    'this is required for binary data

        Try
            SerialPort1.Open()
            Catch ex As IO.IOException
                MsgBox("COULD NOT OPEN COM5")
            End
        End Try
    End Sub
  
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  
        Dim bytearray() As Byte = {&H1F, &H57, &H0, &H0, &H0, &H33, &H37, &H4, &HD} '37

        SerialPort1.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Arduino doesn't support the handshake lines with software, like you did by setting RtsEnable to True.  DtrEnable is the other one.  You'll have to hardwire them.

Comment: I tried connecting DCD-DTR-DSR and RTS-CTS on the RS232-TTL side and still no results.  I'll hook up the volt meter right now.

Comment: That might work.  It is however normally a handshake line for flow control, DTR (on the device end, DSR on your end) is usually the better one.

Comment: I've asked the manufacturer for the device's RJ12 pin out.  The PC interface cable they provide has a female DB9 end with only pins 2 (rx), 3 (tx), 5 (gnd) connected to RJ12 pins 1, 6, and 2.  Once the manufacturer responds what ideal cable should I make?  From what we know now is there a way to guess the device's other 3 RJ12 pins?  The manufacturer might not respond too quick.

Comment: If the handshake signals are not wired on the DB9 connector then it is not handshaking that causes your problem.  And setting RtsEnable to True cannot have any effect.  Easy to check of course, try it again with RtsEnable = False.  What else it might be is unguessable from the question.  Check for voltage level and plain wiring mistakes.